# Copy string value into address

Tags: c++, string

I have the following class

```
class MyClass{
    char myValue[14] //has a 13 character string in it already
public
    void toStr(char* str) const;
}
```

The instruction is: The member function toStr is query that receives the address of a C-style, null-terminated string and fills that address with the object's value
This function assumes that the caller has allocated enough space to hold a thirteen (13) character string.

So I coded:

```
void myClass::toStr(char* str) const
{
std::strcpy(str, myValue);

}
```

However str is receiving the address of myValue and not the string itself. I did quite a bit of searching here and couldn't find anything similiar. I CANNOT use dynamic memory in this exercise.

Comment: Is anything set to myValue? If it's not null terminated strcpy will copy whatever garbage is in memory at myValues location until it hits a null terminator '\0'.

Comment: Please post a full program that shows the error.  We don't know what's behind those variables such as str, or even myValue.

Comment: yes, I removed part of the code but myValue has a 13 character string in it

Comment: str is a pointer to an empty str
myValue has a 13 character string in it

Comment: oh, well that's a problem. str needs to be pre-allocated, at least as long as myValue.

Comment: Don't describe -- actually show a small, but full example of this behavior.

Comment: I can't post the full program here of I get a ZERO for plagiarism

Comment: This function assumes that the caller has allocated enough space to hold a thirteen (13) character string. (for str)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "str is receiving the address of myValue and not the string itself"?

Comment: So you can't just post a 5 or 6 line main() program that shows the error????

Comment: myValue has 1234567890123 but str is not receiving 1234567890123, it's receiving a 0x value, like the place in memory where 1234567890123 is

Comment: How exactly are you seeing that "it's receiving a 0x value"? Give us something we can see ourselves.

Comment: when I debug it I put a break after that function and check the value of str. it's not receiving the 1234567890123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your class used in a simple example (this is all I wanted you to post, but for some reason you couldn't do it).

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    char myValue[14]; 
    public:
        void toStr(char* str) const;
        MyClass() { std::strcpy(myValue, "0123456789012"); }
};

void MyClass::toStr(char* str) const
{ std::strcpy(str, myValue); }

int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    char testString[100];
    m.toStr(testString);
    std::cout << testString;
}
```

This function works as expected.  I see testString being assigned the myValue text.  I added a constructor to MyClass to ensure it is the same as you described, namely that myValue has a 13 character string before the call to toStr.

Now take that example I posted, and either

1) Change whatever you need to change to duplicate your error -- comments can come later as to why what you did doesn't work, or

2) point out what you missed in your code that you see in the example above, thus fixing your error.

There is no plagiarism here, since I have no idea what your assignment is really supposed to be -- this is purely written given your description.  See how easy it is just to provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

In your assignment there is written that str can hold only 13 characters while myValue is defined as an array of 14 characters. So you should use `std::strncpy` instead of `std::strcpy`For example

```
void myClass::toStr(char* str) const
{
    std::strncpy(str, myValue, 13);
    str[12] = '\0';
}
```

I think you get the weird result because myValue is not zero-terminated. If you are considering the both strings as some buffers of bytes then you should use function `std::memcpy`  In this case the function will look as

```
void myClass::toStr(char* str) const
{
    std::memcpy(str, myValue, 13);
}
```

I

Answer (score 0):

We obviously need more information on this. But what I understood, your calling code should be as below:

```
MyClass a;
char *astr = new char[15]; //Allocate enough space for astr to hold myValue
a.toStr(astr);
cout << astr;
delete astr;
```

Also, value should be assigned in constructor or any other setter as below:

```
strcpy(myValue,"Test String");
```

Edit: As explained in another answer by Vlad, `strncpy` should be better.

> This function assumes that the caller has allocated enough space to
>   hold a thirteen (13) character string.

This means before calling your function, your string already allocated space (as I have done with new).

Looks like you mis-understood question.

Comment: Like I said, I cannot allocate dynamic memory for this exercise. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you need to allocate memory in function and copy to your passed pointer.

Comment: and how could I do that?

Comment: @PhillToronto, Actually your exercise assumes that str have memory allocated. See my original answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this! You dont need to bother about myValue array size.

```
void myClass::toStr(char* pstr) const
{ 
    std::string str(myValue);
    pstr = new char[str.size()+1];
    strcpy(pstr, str.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I cannot allocate dynamic memory in this exercise :(